# Get The date time from UTC using offset minutes

Tags: javascript, momentjs

The user have offset minutes from utc which is 360.000009361667 and now I want to have the current user date time using moment

```
function getUserTimeZoneDateTime() {

    var currentUtcDateTime = moment.utc().toDate();
    var mod_start = new Date(currentUtcDateTime.setMinutes(GlobalValues.OffsetMinutesFromUTC - currentUtcDateTime.getTimezoneOffset()));
    var currentUserDateTime= moment(mod_start).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A');

    return currentUserDateTime;
};
```

But this gives me the correct date but the time is not correct
it only gives me 5 PM, 6PM on the time portion the minutes are rounded to 0.

But What I want is the current date and time with minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add minutes to `setMinutes`:

```
function getUserTimeZoneDateTime() {

    var currentUtcDateTime = moment.utc().toDate();
    var mod_start = new Date(currentUtcDateTime.setMinutes(currentUtcDateTime.getMinutes() + GlobalValues.OffsetMinutesFromUTC - currentUtcDateTime.getTimezoneOffset()));
    var currentUserDateTime= moment(mod_start).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A');

    return currentUserDateTime;
};
```

The difference that you use wrong in parenthesis is always an integer number of hours.

You can also use easier way: `moment(obj).utcOffset(OffsetMinutesFromUTC);` to set offset:

```
function getUserTimeZoneDateTime() {
    var currentUtcDateTime = moment.utc().toDate();
    return moment(currentUtcDateTime).utcOffset(GlobalValues.OffsetMinutesFromUTC - currentUtcDateTime.getTimezoneOffset()).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A');
};
```

Comment: Your first solution worked, for the second one I made some changes  I used  return moment(currentUtcDateTime).utcOffset(-GlobalValues.OffsetMinutesFromUTC).format(GlobalValues.DateTimeFormatWSeconds);

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
```

This gets the time and stores it in the variable, here called `now`.
It should get the time wherever the user is.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi K.Davis. I want the datetime per specified offset minutes from utc which is a setting in my application.I was not asking about getting the time where the user is.